# Is $[a,b] \subset B$ necessarily true?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am currently working on a problem, and in order to continue, I need to first make sure if the following statement is true:

Suppose I have a set $A$ which is dense in the interval $[a,b]$. Now let $B$ be a closed set with $A \subseteq B$. Is it necessarily true that $[a,b]\subseteq B$?

My thinking is yes, but I’m struggling to convince myself why it is true. Can anyone please give me an indication if this is true and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is dense in the interval $[a,b]$, then the closure of $A$ contains $[a,b]$.  Since $A\subset B$, the closure of $A$ is contained in the closure of $B$.  Therefore $[a,b]\subset \overline{A}\subset \overline{B} = B$ (where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$, and $\overline{B}=B$ since $B$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the complement of $B$ by $B^c$

Suppose that $[a,b] \not\subseteq B$. Then there exists a point $x \in [a,b]$ with $x \in B^c$. Since $B^c$ is open, there exists an open interval $I$ with $x \in I \subset B^c$.

Since $A$ is dense in $[a,b]$ and $x \in [a,b]$, the interval $I$ must contain a point of $A$. This implies $A \cap B^c \not= \emptyset$, contrary to hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's true. Let $x$ be any point in $[0,1]$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $A$ since $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Therefore $x$ is a limit point of $B$ since $A\subset B$. Since $B$ is closed it contains all of its limit points, therefore $x\in B$.